# Is clang right to complain about an out of line definition of a templated constructor using a concept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, requires-clause

Here is a struct with a templated constructor that is defined out of line:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  template <typename F>
  Foo(F f);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename F>
Foo<T>::Foo(F f) {}
```

Clang [is happy with this](https://godbolt.org/z/erTjc6aab) under `-std=c++20`. If I [add a `requires` clause](https://godbolt.org/z/Wbq6eezMe) to the templated constructor, it is still happy. But if the `requires` clause mentions the struct, it is [not happy](https://godbolt.org/z/aoebMnerf):

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
  template <typename F>
    requires (!std::same_as<Foo<T>, int>)
  Foo(F f);
};

template <typename T>
template <typename F>
  requires (!std::same_as<Foo<T>, int>)
Foo<T>::Foo(F f) {}
```

```
<source>:13:9: error: out-of-line definition of 'Foo<T>' does not match any declaration in 'Foo<T>'
Foo<T>::Foo(F f) {}
        ^~~
```

GCC [does accept this](https://godbolt.org/z/814GqxPqf).

Is clang right to reject it? And if so, what part of the standard says so?

---

If you're interested why I have a `requires` clause that references the type being constructed, it's to disambiguate the constructor from the move constructor so that the next `requires` clause in a larger `requires` expression won't be evaluated when `F` is the same as `Foo` . Otherwise it recursively depends upon itself. The real code is more complicated, and accepts a forwarding reference to `F`.

Comment: I think it's just a Clang bug. N.b. Clang 16 appears to work if you use a trailing requires clause instead of one following the template parameter list, but Clang 15 is just a lost cause (it also doesn't implement [P0848](https://wg21.link/p0848)).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this, but you could forward declare the class and a concept: https://godbolt.org/z/3h7ssT4M6 or https://godbolt.org/z/KWMrTPYGc

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, using a trailing clause (after the function signature) is a good workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be related to the compiler not being able to deduce what T is. When using a requires clause inside a struct, the compiler needs to be able to instantiate the class template in order to check the requirements specified in the requires clause. This means that all template parameters used within the requires clause must be in scope and the compiler must be able to deduce their types.
If the class template is not fully defined yet, the compiler will not be able to instantiate it, and the code will not be able to compile. Just to be clear, I do not know with certainty, as I have barely used this feature.

Answer (score 0):

As I sort of expected, this seems to be a known clang bug: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/49620